# Cygwin: Using cronjob for starting an Windows batch-file

Tags: linux, windows-xp, cygwin

I try to create a cronjob under Cygwin that starts an extern batchfile. Well, if it would be possible I could also try to run a sh script but the problem is:

I try to use truecrypt and java, or more detailed: Try to mount a container, synchronize a directory with a java jar-commandline tool and close the container subsequently

I am unable to pass the parameters, e.g.:

/cygdrive/e/backup/truecrypt.exe /v "e:\dropbox\projects.secured" ... doesnt work

and

java -jar Sync.jar "E:\home\git" "Z:" doesnt, too...

Do you have an idea? the problem is, that there isnt a native install for java and truecrypt under cygwin.

Thanks a lot for your help ...!

Answer (score 1):

After some minutes I found a solution for this problem:

I don't know why it works better than a batch but I am invoking a *.cmd-file now. I am not any longer searching for a "sh-solution" which doesn't work in this case with cygwin.

Now my file looks like:

```
e:/backup/truecrypt /v "E:\path\to\my\tcfile\container.tc" /p mygreatpass ...
java -jar Sync.jar --ignorewarnings ...
e:/backup/truecrypt /d /q /f
```

Comment: funny behavior but at least it works for me now! Thanks much for posting your solution.